# Which conjugation is this 進む → 進め

Tags: translation, conjugations, imperatives

I'm translating a song and came across the following sentence:

> 明日の岸辺へと夢の舟よ進め

If it was 明日の岸辺へと夢の舟よ進む it would mean "move on the dream boat to the shores of tomorrow". What changes with this conjugation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Imperative

Answer (score 6):

This is the [命令形]{めい・れい・けい} - imperative form.  It translates more like

> O dream boat, go/move on to the shore of tomorrow

Which is almost what you have.  The difference is that the singer is addressing the boat (夢の船**よ**), not saying "go on" the boat.